# Greedy NSProgressIndicator Allocation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, memory, memory-management

I'm using a bunch of NSProgressIndicators at once (32 to be exact) and it looks like when they're animating they start allocating memory like no one's business
[image: greedy_run]

I've got reports that the app will slowdown and eventually crash after days of uptime, and this looks like the most likely culprit, but it's hard to pinpoint bugs that take days to appear.

I simply comment out the call to start animating, all memory behaves as expected. Could this be a result of multiple NSProgressIndicators alloc'ed on the same thread? or maybe sandboxing? All of the constant allocations are coming from Core Animation threads, I don't know what else could be going on.

Custom NSView that the progress indicator lives in

```
@interface MyView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTextView *numberTxt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSProgressIndicator *progress;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
if (self) {
    // Image
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    self.imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(rect)];
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self addSubview:self.imageView];

    // Number
    CGRect numberRect = CGRectMake(0, 30, image.size.width, 40);
    self.numberTxt = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(numberRect)];
    [self.numberTxt setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [self.numberTxt setEditable:NO];
    [self.numberTxt setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:30]];
    [self.numberTxt setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:self.numberTxt];

    // Progress
    CGRect progressRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5 - 20, self.frame.size.height * 0.5 - 20, 40, 40);
    self.progress = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(progressRect)];
    [self.progress setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];

    //This line, when commented, fixes things
    [self.progress startAnimation:self];
    //
    [self addSubview:self.progress];
}

return self;
}
```

Comment: What is this `startAnimation` method?

Comment: As an aside: don't use `self` inside your init (and `dealloc`) methods! Instead access the ivars directly.

Comment: Also you shouldn't do any UI related stuff in init methods since it might (most probably) isn't completely setup. Do them instead in e.g. `awakeFromNib`

Comment: @Merlevede startAnimation: is a method on NSProgressIndicator that does exactly that, start the animation. It's the same as startAnimating from a UIProgressIndicator (the arguement of sender in NSProgressIndicator mystifies me though, it seems to work no matter what is passed in)

Comment: @HAS I was fishing around with ivars vs properties before no luck there, and I've just tried `MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init]; [view.progress startAnimation:view];`. Still no dice :/

Comment: so the growth unbounded? does it show with 1 in that case?

Comment: do you do stuff in layoutSubviews / didLayout or willLayout or so ... any method triggered by redrawing the window often?

Comment: can you discern what types of objects are allocated?

Comment: @HAS self in init is totally fine after the super class is called and when not using xibs anyway, you dont/cant/no need to wait for awakeFromNib